# Add text above the textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is the code which I'm using to create a textarea in a div.

```
var customDiv = $('<div />', { class: 'myCustDiv'});
customDiv.append( $('<textarea />', { class: 'mycustTextarea' }) );
```

How do I add text above the textarea? See below expected output:

[image]

Comment: Just add `customDiv.append( $('<p>Add your number</p>') );` in the second line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `<label>` element, for example:

```
var customDiv = $('<div />', { class: 'myCustDiv'});
customDiv.append( $('<label>Add Your Number</label>' );
customDiv.append( $('<textarea />', { class: 'mycustTextarea' }) );
```

To add `class` names you can use HTML attributes instead of passing object:

```
customDiv.append( $('<label class="myTextareaLabel">Add Your Number</label>' );
```

Comment: Looks good. thanks. If there are multiple lables, how do I control styling for each label?

Comment: You can pass `class` attribute. Just use `customDiv.append( $('<label class="myLabelClass">Add Your Number</label>' );`

Comment: @Beki sorry, look at my updated comment above. Just edited it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var customDiv = $('<div />', { class: 'myCustDiv', html: 'Add Your number'});
customDiv.append( $('<textarea />', { class: 'mycustTextarea' }) );
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7rcyqzrd/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/m746o0bq/)

```
var customDiv = $("<div class='myCustDiv'></div>"),
    textArea = $(customDiv).append(("<textarea class='mycustTextarea'>")),
    blockText = $("<p>Block of Text</p>");
$('#printArea').append(textArea);
$(customDiv).prepend(blockText)
```